# Building Symfony 2 Custom Validator that Uses Multiple Fields

Tags: symfony

I'm building a custom validator that needs to validate the value from TWO form fields in the db in order to get this constraint to pass.

My question is this: the ContractValidator's validate method only has one $value in it's signature so how do I get access to the values from more than just a single field to do the validation?

Here is a typical custom validator:

```
namespace Acme\WebsiteBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class MyCustomValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
  {
    // check $value and return an error
    // but in my case, i want the value from more than one form field to do a validation
    // why? i'm checking that two pieces of information (ssn + dob year) match
    // the account the user is registering for
  }
}
```

Here's an example of a form class with some validations set:

```
namespace ACME\WebsiteBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use ACME\WebsiteBundle\Validator\Constraints\UsernameAvailable;

class AccountRegistration extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('ssn', 'number', array(
      'max_length' => 9, 
      'required' => true,
      'error_bubbling' => true)
    );

    $builder->add('year_of_birth', 'choice', array(
      'choices'  => range(date("Y") - 100, date("Y")),
      'required' => true,
      'empty_value' => 'Select ...',
      'label'    => 'Year of Birth',
      'error_bubbling' => true)
    );

    $builder->add('username', 'text', array(
      'required' => true,
      'error_bubbling' => true)
    );

    $builder->add('password', 'password', array(
      'max_length' => 25,
      'required' => true,
      'error_bubbling' => true)
    );

    $builder->add('security_question', 'choice', array(
      'empty_value' => 'Select ...',
      'choices' => array(),
      'label' => 'Security Question',
      'required' => true,
      'error_bubbling' => true)
    );

    $builder->add('security_question_answer', 'text', array(
      'label' => 'Answer',
      'required' => true,
      'error_bubbling' => true)
    );
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'account_registration';
  }

  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
  {

    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
      'allowExtraFields' => true, 
      'fields' => array(
        'ssn'  => array(new MinLength(array('limit' => 9, 'message' => 'too short.')), new NotBlank()),
        'year_of_birth' => array(new NotBlank()),
        'username' => array(new NotBlank(), new UsernameAvailable()),
        'password' => array(new NotBlank(), new Regex(array(
          'message' => 'password must be min 8 chars, contain at least 1 digit',
          'pattern' => "((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{8,25})"))
        ),
        'security_question' => array(new NotBlank()),
        'security_question_answer' => array(new NotBlank()))
      )
    );

    return array(
        'csrf_protection' => true,
        'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
        'intention'       => 'account_registration',
        'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint
    );
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Any custom validator that extends `ConstraintValidator` has access to the `$context` property. `$context` is an instance of `ExecutionContext` that gives you access to submitted data:

Example:

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;


class AppointorRoleValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $values = $this->context->getRoot()->getData();
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the Entity and not the form data... so pretty much useless.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `CLASS_CONSTRAINT` as described in the [cookbooks](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator). You then get passed the whole class and can use any property of this class. In your example above, this would mean that instead of the `$value` beeing one string/integer, it would be the whole object you want to validate.

The only thing you need to change is `getTargets()` functions, which has to return `self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT`.

Also make sure that you define your validator on class level, not on property level. If you use annotations this means that the validator must be described above the class defnition, not above one specific attribute definition:

```
/**
  * @MyValidator\SomeValidator
  */
class MyClass {

}
```

Comment: I'm not validating against a class. I'm just creating a standalone form of AbstractType.

Comment: But you have some object you are validating? If not, could you show the code on how you set validations?

Comment: Added. You'll need to scroll to see the whole thing, but this is the account registration form. You can see the validation constraints I've already added at the bottom.

Comment: I guess there must be some way to do this. I actually never work with forms without objects, so I don't know how to do this. As said in the docs, generating forms without an object should be done for small forms only.