# symfony form with required only if one field blank

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I need to create a form with 4 fields (uid, firstname, lastname, birthday).

- if uid is completed the 3 others is not required
- if uid is empty the 3 others is required and respect constraint.

How can I do this ? I think I must use formEvent (pre submit) ? and get data, check data but after ? add constraint ? add error ?

Comment: You could create a custom validator. Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363640/building-symfony-2-custom-validator-that-uses-multiple-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a form event and generate an error if the form is not completed properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FormEvents in order to achieve dynamic Validation.

This is the documentation you should checkout:

[see here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)